# How to exempt weekends from freshness checks in Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga, check-mk

Thank you, serverfault, for giving me the answer to [how-does-an-administrator-generalize-alerting-when-an-event-doesnt-happen](https://serverfault.com/questions/555128/how-does-an-administrator-generalize-alerting-when-an-event-doesnt-happen).

Now, I only want to check the freshness of these passive services Monday through Friday.

There are some subtleties:

- The status should be allowed to improve over the weekend.
- The status should never degrade over the weekend.
- Notifications should still be emitted over the weekend.

Best I can come up with is YACS - Yet Another Cron Script (to shave).  But even then, wouldn't the service definitions need to be toggled every week?  Is this service definition dynamism often done with Nagios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use time periods in Nagios :

- http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/timeperiods.html
- http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#timeperiod

If you want different behaviours between Week days and Week-end, i cannot see another way to do it without duplicate the service check :

- Configure your first service check with a time period from Monday to
  Friday, and with the required behaviour for this period.
- Then, configure the duplicated service check with a time period from
  Saturday to Sunday, and with the required behaviour for this period.

I don't like the duplicate service idea, but i am not aware about other ways to do it...that is actually the way i proceed myself in my Nagios config...

Comment: The depth of nagios never seems to end.

However, the docs state that "On-demand checks and passive checks are not restricted by the timeperiod you specify in the check_period directive. Only regularly scheduled active checks are restricted."

Comment: Defining duplicate checks... that would work or active checks.  Very nice.

Comment: Actually I found this in the icinga docs:
"The check_period option in your host and service definitions is used when Icinga determines when a host or service can be checked for freshness, so make sure it is set to a valid timeperiod."

Comment: You also might be able to do this with an escalation that's only valid during certain timeperiods